# Use value of enum class for bitshift shift operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The following snippet...

```
enum class A {
        X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 2,
    };

int s = (1 << A::X);
```

...yields the following compile error:

```
error C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a 
left-hand operand of type 'int' 
(or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

What's the best and cleanest way to make this bitshift work?

Comment: You could do `int s = (1 << (int)A::X);` if you insist on the `enum class`.

Comment: Or `int s = (1 << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<A>>(A::x));` if you want to be extra safe. Alternatively, overload `operator<<` for this `enum class`.

Answer (score 2):

A small utility function might help to clarify intent while guaranteeing correctness:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class Enum>
auto to_bitmask(Enum e)
{
    using type = std::underlying_type_t<Enum>;
    return 1 << type(e);
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/_pp7VW

For a more generic version, c++17 allows easy treatment of any enum or integer type:

```
template<class Enum>
constexpr auto to_bitmask(Enum e)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<Enum>() || std::is_enum<Enum>());

    if constexpr (std::is_enum<Enum>())
    {
        using type = std::underlying_type_t<Enum>;
        return 1 << type(e);
    }
    else 
    {
        return 1 << e;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will cause a narrowing conversion when `type` is bigger than `unsigned int`. I'd either remove the trailing return type (C++14), and let the correct thing happen, or use something like `std::common_type` (for C++11).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better style to `static_cast<type>(e)`? I get that there's no effective difference here, but it's still more defensive...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Maybe, it probably depends on style preferences. 
My thinking is this: (1) I've already implicitly asserted that the type is an enum. (2) I prefer succinct correctness to wordy correctness. I know some others prefer wordiness.

Answer (score 1):

A scoped enumeration is strongly typed. You need to explicitly define the operators you wish to support, for there is no implicit conversion to an integer that can make the built in operator viable.

If you want to enable the implicit conversion to an int, without giving up the identifier scoping, you can use an "old style" scoped enumeration. I.e., wrap it in a class type instead:

```
struct A {
   enum Type {
        X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 2,
   };
};
```

Since unscoped enumerators are also members of the enclosing scope, you can write `1 << A::X` still, and it will produce the desired effect. The price is of course that now the enumeration name is the more verbose `A::Type`.

Answer (score 0):

The following way work. Cmd：g++ test.cc

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    enum A {
        X = 0, Y , Z
    };

    int s = (1 << Y);
    std::cout <<"s = "<< s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's not a good solution, because it exports X, Y and Z into the surrounding namespace. That's exactly what one tries to avoid when using class enum.